# Excel Password and carving out Tab name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm in the process of setting up a Macro to open up all files in a directory and copy a certain tab from each into a combined file (merge them in one workbook).  I have two problems.  Firstly the files are password protected - So when I use this line it opens the file.

```
Set gwkbInputdata = Workbooks.Open(gRnCT_File_Loc & gsInputFileName)
```

However when it's password protected it fails.  So I added the following to the end but it still fails.

```
Set gwkbInputdata = Workbooks.Open(gRnCT_File_Loc & gsInputFileName),Password = "openfile"
```

2nd issue - When I copy the tabs (sheets) in I want to name them with the file name I took them from.  However the file name is too long - So I want to take the name up to the first space (e.g. "Test file May 13" = sheet name "Test").  How do I get this code to work.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Full code below:

*** gRnCT_File_Loc = Directory location.
*** gsInputFileName = File Name.

```
Code to date:

Sub Pulldata()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set gRwksconfigeration = Sheets(gcsConfigSheetName)
gRnCT_File_Loc = gRwksconfigeration.Range(CT_File_Loc)
gRnCT_Tab_Search = gRwksconfigeration.Range(CT_Tab_Search)
gsInputFileName = Dir(gRnCT_File_Loc)
Set gwkscurrent = ActiveWorkbook

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
       If ws.Name <> gcsConfigSheetName Then ws.Delete
Next ws

Do
    On Error GoTo err:
        Set gwkbInputdata = Workbooks.Open(gRnCT_File_Loc & gsInputFileName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    On Error GoTo err1:
        With Sheets(gRnCT_Tab_Search)
    On Error GoTo 0

        End With

gsInputFileName = Dir
Loop Until gsInputFileName = vbNullString

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Exit Sub

err:
    MsgBox ("No files or files in incorrect format in " & gRnCT_File_Loc)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub
err1:
    MsgBox ("Sheet " & gRnCT_Tab_Search & " doesn't exist in file " & gsInputFileName)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `:` after password

```
Set gwkbInputdata = Workbooks.Open(gRnCT_File_Loc & gsInputFileName),Password = "openfile"
```

should be:

```
Set gwkbInputdata = Workbooks.Open(gRnCT_File_Loc & gsInputFileName,Password:="openfile")
```

You could use `split` for your second problem using a space as your delimiter e.g.

```
Split(str, " ")(0)
```

where `str` is the original name of the file e.g. "Test file May 13"

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. Greatly appreciated. Alistair - when I add in the missing ":" (I'm buying glasses) - I get a compil error: Expected: end of statement at this point "," password:="Test"  "," appears to be the issue but I can't see it.

Comment: Thanks all - Finally got it - nothing a pair of glasses won't fix. Really appreciate the support.

Answer (score 3):

For the 2nd question about getting the 1st part of the file name, try:

```
if(instr(gsInputFileName," ") > 0
   then short_file_name=left(gsInputFileName,instr(gsInputFileName," ")-1)
   else short_file_name=gsInputFileName
   endif
```